# how could I randomize a jQuery tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am going to use on of the tooltip plugins listed in this question: [jquery tooltip, but on click instead of hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313321/jquery-tooltip-but-on-click-instead-of-hover)

How would I also setup a tooltip that randomized the text shown. For instance if you click a link you could be shown one of three possible messages:

Message 1
Message 2
Message 3

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually have an array of messages and then generate a random index onclick.

something like

```
 var messageArray = ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3"];
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*messageArray.size);
 var myMessage = messageArray[randomNum];
```

or something like that. refactor to use ajax/your db if you need to

Comment: Corroded, this looks great.  I am newer to JS, how could I apply this to a tooltip that has its message hardcoded into the html?

Comment: what do you mean its hard coded? the message array is hardcoded into your html?

Answer (score 0):

Using a very small function from PHP.js: http://phpjs.org/functions/rand:498

I do it like so:

```
var messages = [
    'Message 1',
    'Message 2',
    'Message 3'
];

var random_number = rand(0, messages.length);
$("#tooltip").text(messages[random_number]);

// PHP.js rand() function.
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Leslie Hoare
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman

function rand (min, max) {
    var argc = arguments.length;
    if (argc === 0) {
        min = 0;
        max = 2147483647;
    } else if (argc === 1) {
        throw new Error('Warning: rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given');
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Why use PHP.js's `rand` function when JavaScript's `Math` object works just fine? (also, `length` is a property, not a method)

Comment: Force of habit. Using JS's Math.random() function would be more ideal. Corroded provided a more concise solution above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var messages = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3'];

$('.withTooltip').click(function(){
  $("#tooltip").text(messages[Math.round(Math.random() * 3)]).show();
});
```

Comment: So I wound up going with: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/  It loads the tooltip from a paragraph tag.  Any ideas how to get it done like that?