# Appear / Disappear message onclick (tooltip?)

Tags: javascript, onclick, tooltip

I want to show a "Item added" message like on [**jCarts** demo](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/) but that will be triggered by clicking a ordinary `<a href>`-link.
I've searched for "tooltip onclick" but you have to click again to close the tooltips in every script I've found, and I don't know how to correct that.
I just want a message in a simple box to show when you click a link and then it disappears, just like on jCarts demo.

Can I call that a tooltip or what shall I search for?
How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Usually tooltips are shown on 'mouseenter' event, and closed on 'mouseleave' event (with possible delay). Everything you have to change is to show this tooltip on 'click' event instead of 'mouseenter'.

See this question: [jquery tooltip, but on click instead of hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313321/jquery-tooltip-but-on-click-instead-of-hover)

Comment: Thank you, but will it be closed on mouseleave then, or when does it close?

Comment: Some libs has api to show/hide tooltip box - you can just bind it to proper events. You can also make own tooltip, its not very complicated.