# Show tooltip text by clicking a control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically show tooltip in winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439/programatically-show-tooltip-in-winforms-application)

When set a TooltipText on a control, and the tooltip text will be shown when user move mouse on the control.

Now I have a picturebox on a windows form, what I want is to display the tooltip text by clicking the control instead of hover it.

How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the following page and see if that helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313321/jquery-tooltip-but-on-click-instead-of-hover

Comment: @GazWinter his question is clearly marked as C# winforms, how does a jquery question help?

Comment: @JustinPihony yeah sorry I just noticed that. Ignore my comment.

Comment: It's really like this [Programatically show tooltip in winforms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439/programatically-show-tooltip-in-winforms-application)

Comment: @Steve It's slightly different than that question in the sense that he also wants it to show the tool tip that is assigned to the control, not just any random text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will do the trick:

```
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int durationMilliseconds = 10000;
    ToolTip1.Show(ToolTip1.GetToolTip(PictureBox1), PictureBox1, durationMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: It works out. But it disappears after a few seconds. Is there a default delay setting time?

Comment: @Love Ha!  Good point.  I do too much switching back and forth between languages on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Tooltip has a [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884812ce) function. Just use that as necessary